# How to query SQL Server table with XML column (as string) using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I use LINQ to SQL to query a table with an XML datatype column as an IQueryable?

SQL Server table:

```
Id [int]
SomeData [xml]
```

An example of SomeData could be:

```
<container><Person>Joe Smith</person></container>
```

In T-SQL, I can query the table like this to find employees with a specific nam,e :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [MyTable]
WHERE 
    SomeData.value('(//*[local-name()="Person"])[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'Joe Smith'
```

Or to treat the xml as a string, to search for a string regardless of xml schema:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [MyTable]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(max), SomeData) like '%Joe Smith%'
```

Now I turn to LINQ to SQL, and want to perform the second query:

```
var myTable = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeData.Value.Contains("Joe Smith"));
```

I get the error:

```
"The member 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Value' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

**I understand why I get the error, but is there a way to work around it?**

Being able to query the column as a string (with no concept of xml-structure) is completely fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view that exposes the Xml column as varchar(...) and query that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Contains you can use System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like().

`var myTable = db.MyTable.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.SomeData, "%Joe Smith%"));`

Answer (score 0):

Import xml file into a temporary table with a xml column and THE try to parse the file and put it into a relational table.